# json-server-auth not working when starting

Tags: json, angular

i wanted to use json-server-auth but after installing it with npm it does not start.. I get this error:

```html
json-server-auth : The term 'json-server-auth' is not recognized as the name of a 
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or  
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ json-server-auth db.json
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (json-server-auth:String) [], CommandNot  
   FoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Can someone tell me how to resolve this issue and start the json-server-auth because i need it for my angular application because i am learning authentication and i am stuck here because of this error..

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

i used this command to start the server and it started without an issue:

```html
json-server db.json -m ./node_modules/json-server-auth
```